# Call methods for objects retrived from Memcached

Tags: python, linux, django, memcached

Having some object that I need shared between two python processes on the same machine , I use python memcached to store objects in a process and use them in the other process. However even if they can be retrieved in the process that wants to use them, calling their methods returns nothing (not the expected result).

Should someone the necessary input, what happens in such a described scenario 
 - is the object passed entirely and both process share it's state ? , or only a copy is passed and changes made by one process are not visible in the other
 - what other techniques / libraries could be employed in order to achieve sharing objects between python processes.

Thanks

Comment: Memcached stores strings only. Passing objects may be achieved by serialising and unserialising them before write and after read from the cache respectively. But there are more efficient ways to share objects between processes like [IPC](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ipc.html).

Answer (score 0):

Memcached stores string values and not rich objects as you describe.

What you describe sounds like a publisher-subscriber application - one process produces data and the other process acts on it.

Memcached is not the right tool for pub/sub.  You need a list that you can atomically add to and pop from.  While you can store a string representation of a list in Memcached, you cannot add and remove elements from this list atomically amongst processes.

Have a look at [Redis](http://redis.io).  It has rich data structures that are ideal for pub/sub and mature [Python clients](http://redis.io/clients#python) to use.

For a simple implementation you could have your one process add ([LPUSH](http://redis.io/commands/lpush)) data to a list.  The other process could pop ([RPOP](http://redis.io/commands/rpop)) data off this list and run a method on it.  This would give you a good IPC queue that scales well.

If you need more sophistication then look at the [Redis pub/sub docs](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) - it has a messaging system that eliminates the need to poll a queue for new values.